# ember data 1.13.8 and ember cli mirage confusion

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

This is my Ember inspector info tab:

[image]

I am using ember-cli-mirage and I'm facing issue here.

I am not able to get belongsTo relationship of a model. When I do `car.get('user')`, I get a promise in result which gets fullfilled but the value is always `null`.

My user model
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('String'),
  car: DS.belongsTo('car',{async: true})
});
```

My car model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr('String'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user',{async: true})
});
```

my mirage/config

```
  this.get('/cars',function(db,request) {
    var qp = request.queryParams.searchString.toLowerCase();
    return {
      cars: db.cars.where({'color':qp}),
      users: db.users
    };
  });
```

I get the list of cars with search color but I don't get the user.
it returns a promise which when fullfilled gives null.

Since I am using ember-data 1.13.8

I tried using this [Mirage working with json](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/working-with-json-api/) but then I get error
datum model is not defined error so i guess new json api is not my issue for some reason my ember data uses old json format and original config works.

```
this.get('/cars', function(db, request) {
  return {
    data: db.cars.map(attrs => (
      {type: 'cars', id: attrs.id, attributes: attrs }
    ))
  };
})
```

My cars route look like this

```
 model: function(params) {
    self = this;
    if(!params){
        return [];
    }
    return this.store.findQuery('car',params);
  },
```

I tried

```
return this.store.findQuery('car',params).then(function(item){
      console.log(item.get('user'));
    });
```

but i still got `console.log //undefined`

I can see user_id in my json returned.

**SOLUTION:**
 found the issue i was saving relationship as `user_id = user.id.` It should be `user=user.id`

Comment: I found the issue i was saving relationship as user_id = user.id. It should be user=user.id

Comment: You should post this as an answer in this question and mark your answer as accepted. This way everyone will know that you found solution and question will no longer be marked as unanswered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: found the issue i was saving relationship as `user_id = user.id`. It should be `user=user.id`